# meaning of <> after class extend in dart

Tags: syntax, dart, flutter

I am reading the [beginner tutorial of flutter](https://flutter.io/get-started/codelab/#step-3-add-a-stateful-widget), and when I found the `<RandomWords>` part I don't know what it really means.

```
class RandomWordsState extends State<RandomWords> {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe State<> is a generic class, and Random words is a generic argument for that class. It basically means that you are tailoring the inherited RandomWordsState class so it is specialised for dealing with RandomWords.

Further reading ... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming